# Error creating a new DbCommand

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to create a new DbCommand, but get some errors:

```
DbCommand insertcommand = new DbCommand("insert into persons(firstname, lastname, email) values(?, ?, ?)", connection);
insertcommand.Parameters.Add(1, DbType.String, 50, "fistname");
insertcommand.Parameters.Add(2, DbType.String, 50, "lastname");
insertcommand.Parameters.Add(3, DbType.String, 100, "email");
dbAdapter.InsertCommand = insertcommand;
```

This yields the errors

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class Or interface
>   "System.Data.Common.DbCommand"

and

> No overload for method 'Add' takes 4 arguments

How should I be creating these commands and populating the parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normally need to *either* create a concrete instance directly (`new SqlCommand` etc) or use [`IDbConnection.CreateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.createcommand.aspx).

It's not clear which is the most appropriate for your situation.

As for the `Add` calls - if you use a concrete command type, you may well have more overloads available to you. Otherwise you'll probably want to use [`IDbCommand.CreateParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.createparameter.aspx), set properties, then add it to the parameter collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new SQLParameter and add everything to that.  Then, pass the SQLParameter as your parameter.  Parameters.Add only takes in one parameter, I believe, and that would be your SQLParameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: the link is dead ☠